# Why access c_str returned from object on the heap get garbage value?

Tags: c++

Sometimes I need to call C++ objects from C. After some search, I know I can use `extern "C"` to wrap some interfaces which can be called from C. Here is my code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class Dog
{
public:
    Dog(std::string nm = "Eddie"): name(nm), sound("woof")
    {
        std::cout << "Dog " << name << " is coming." << std::endl;
    }
    ~Dog()
    {
        std::cout << "Dog " << name << " ran way." << std::endl;
    }
    std::string bark()
    {
        return sound;
    }
private:
    std::string name;
    std::string sound;
};

extern "C" {
    void * dog_come();
    void   dog_delete(void *);
    const char * dog_bark(void *);
}

void * dog_come()
{
    return new Dog();
}

void dog_go(void *pd)
{
    delete (Dog *)pd;
}

const char * dog_bark(void *pd)
{
    Dog *pdog = (Dog *)pd;
    return pdog->bark().c_str();
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    Dog hobo("Hobo");
    std::cout << hobo.bark() << std::endl;

    void *eddie = dog_come();
    std::cout << dog_bark(eddie) << std::endl;
    dog_go(eddie);

    return 0;
}
```

After execute the following command:

```
g++ -std=c++11 main.cpp
./a.out
```

I think the output should be:

```
Dog Hobo is coming.
woof
Dog Eddie is coming.
woof
Dog Eddie ran way.
Dog Hobo ran way.
```

However, the real output I got is:

```
Dog Hobo  is coming.
woof
Dog Eddie  is coming.
$%^& /**< garbage here */
Dog Eddie ran way.
Dog Hobo ran way.
```

Can someone tell me why?

Comment: `return pdog->bark().c_str();` `bark()` returns a temporary object. It's destroyed when returning. `c_str` is a pointer to something inside the return value of  `bark`. Therefore the memory `c_str`s return value points to, is temporary. By the time you get to `dog_go(eddie);` the memory pointed to by `eddie` has been free'd.

Comment: Change Dog::bark to `const std::string& bark() { return sound; }`.

Comment: With this change you will not return a C++ specific type to C code. dog_bark code now gets a temporary string and returns it's content. After exiting dog_bark, the string is destroyed and it's contents can become garbage. With my change dog_bark will get a pointer to a string from Dog object, that's allocated on the heap. dog_bark still returns a const char* but this time not to a temporary object that will not be destroyed after dog_bark exits.

Comment: Not properly understanding how temporaries works is a proof that one should read a few good books on C++.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best solution is to modify the code as follows :

```cpp
   std::string bark() { return sound; }
```

into

```cpp
   const std::string& bark() { return sound; }
```

Which equally leads to a correct execution and a correct code.

If however you want to stick to the method provided in your original code and only solve the problem, here is an alternative.

When you call your function :

```c
const char * dog_bark(void *pd)
{
    Dog *pdog = (Dog *)pd; 
    return pdog->bark().c_str();
}
```

You code `return pdog->bark().c_str();` does the following:

- `std::string tmp(pdog->bark())` which is destroyed as soon as you go out of the function.
- `tmp.c_str();` is valid as long as you do not go out of the function. But when you go out, this becomes a `dangling pointer`

An alternative could be to declare a global buffer (`char* buffer`) that `dog_bark()` and `main()` can access for its allocation and for its `deallocation`.

You could use this buffer to transfer the pointer as you would like to (but you then have to allocate it first) and after using it delete it.

Here is my proposition, I only put the modified code:

```c
char * buffer = NULL;

const char* dog_bark(void *pd)
{
    Dog *pdog = (Dog *)pd;
    //allocate a buffer of the same length as the string to convert
    buffer = (char*)malloc( pdog->bark().length()*sizeof(char));
    // copy the value of the string into the buffer
    strcpy(buffer, pdog->bark().c_str());
    //return the buffer
    return buffer;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    Dog hobo("Hobo");
    std::cout << hobo.bark() << std::endl;

    void *eddie = dog_come();
    std::cout << dog_bark(eddie) << std::endl;
    dog_go(eddie);
    //free the buffer
    free(buffer);
    return 0;
}
```

The execution does what you wanted.

Comment: Very bad idea to tells other peoples how to write bad code. It is well known that global variables are evils for at least 20 years. Even worst, is the fact that it does a memory allocation that the user need to be aware as otherwise, there will be a memory leak. Also very bad idea to mix C and C++ allocation. You only increase the chance that something will go wrong. Even worst, it is not multithread safe if the call use 2 distinct dogs from 2 different threads.

Comment: @Phil1970 Could you provide a better solution or a suggestion, please?

Comment: **The alternative is correct...** Usually if one seek answers, he might not be aware of all the pitfalls, so it is important to either avoid them in an answer or be clear about it.

Comment: Adding to @Phil1970 's points the fact, that in the context of C code, return values are not always the best option. I usually stuck to the pattern of having the caller provide a buffer, thus alleviating responsibilities and decisions to the caller. So, instead - for a C-friendly API, I would suggest: `bool_ish bark(size_t buffer_capacity, char* buffer)`. I use the `bool_ish`, here because bool does not exist in C and stdbool.h was flawed especially for C - C++ interop. I usually used int instead, with int being the only "naked" type.